# ajax beginner, please help (json encode in php and data variable in ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Total beginner with javascript and ajax. I wasted two days could not figure this out...

I've processor.php which contains: `echo json_encode('ok');`

My ajax submits form to that file and receives response ok.

Now I want to use that ok inside my function:

```
success: function (data) {
if (data == "ok") {
//do smth
}
```

Unfortunately this if never evaluates true.

I check alert(data); inside success function and I get "ok"

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this `echo json_encode('ok');` to `echo 'ok'`;

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode('ok')` is `"ok"`, not `ok`.  Try comparing `data == '"ok"'`, or handle this in some other way.

Comment: What if I do json_encode(array("status" => "ok"))
How do I get array status? alert(data[status]) doesn't work...

Comment: @SandroDzneladze it would have to be `data['status']` or `data.status`

Comment: Thanks! I used other answer, but upvoted yours too for help! :)